# Sorting array recursive

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
var a = [
  {id: 1, pid: 0},
  {id: 2, pid: 1},
  {id: 3, pid: 1},
  {id: 4, pid: 2},
  {id: 5, pid: 2},
  {id: 6, pid: 3},
  {id: 7, pid: 3}
]
```

And a map object like this:

```
var map = {
  "1": {id: 1, pid: 0},
  "2": {id: 2, pid: 1},
  "3": {id: 3, pid: 1},
  "4": {id: 4, pid: 2},
  "5": {id: 5, pid: 2},
  "6": {id: 6, pid: 3},
  "7": {id: 7, pid: 3}
}
```

I am trying to sort it to match this pattern:

```
var result = [
  {"id": 1, "pid": 0},
    {"id": 2, "pid": 1},
      {"id": 4, "pid": 2},
      {"id": 5, "pid": 2},
    {"id": 3, "pid": 1},
      {"id": 6, "pid": 3},
      {"id": 7, "pid": 3}
]
```

As you can see this is a nested tree structure. And I want to get `pid` under the matching `id` and the lowest `id` at the top.

Is there any way to sort an array like this using only one iteration? - if not, it would be nice to see an example on how to get around it.

So far I only have:

```
a.sort(function(q, w) { return q.pid - w.pid; });
```

And I'm thinking of using my map to find my parent using `pid`->`id` and then sort on that key. It's okay to store extra properties on my objects as well.

Comment: You're indenting it like it's nested, but you haven't actually nested any arrays or objects.

Comment: You ***can't*** do that with a simple comparison function that only knows about two elements!

Comment: @Barmar I think he's aware of that, basically, he wants to have a tree and then linearize with pre-order.

Comment: @Barmar the reason why I'am indenting the result is just for clarity - at least i thought.

Comment: @phant0m Do you care to elaborate? I can't see to figure out why you can't

Comment: `sort()` looks at each pair of array elements and needs to know which one is higher or lower. But your ordering is based on parent-child relationships between specific elements.

Comment: You can do it with a recursive algorithm, but I'm too tired to write it now.

Comment: @Null Barmar is correct. Unless the pair happens to be a father-child pair, you can't tell what the sort order has to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there is a single root with pid 0:

```
var children = {}
var root = null;
a.forEach(function(e) {
    children[e.id] = [];
});

a.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.pid === 0) {
        root = e;
    }
    else {
        children[e.pid].push(e);
    }
});

var sorted = [];

function preorder(e) {
    sorted.push(e);
    if (children.hasOwnProperty(e.id)) {
        children[e.id].forEach(preorder);
    }
}
preorder(root);
```

Result:

```
[
  {"id":1,"pid":0},
    {"id":2,"pid":1},
    {"id":4,"pid":2},
      {"id":5,"pid":2},
    {"id":3,"pid":1},
      {"id":6,"pid":3},
      {"id":7,"pid":3}
]
```